# Code Golf: Movement in 3 Dimensions

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf

Assuming a 3 dimensional irregular matrix where `y = 1.5(x) and z = .5(y)`.

Further assuming an object starts at `0,0,0` and must move positively in at least two dimensions, and must move in all three dimensions (`x+1, y+1, z-1` is okay, `x+1, y+1, z=z` is not).  It may move any number of "spaces", but must move the same number in all directions.

The object is allowed to wraparound `(x(max +1) = x(0))`.

Move said object from its starting position to `(0, max(y), .5(max(z)))` For `z`, round up for fractions (end point in 4, 6, 3 matrix becomes 0, 6, 2)

Input is an Integer (X).

Output is the list of moves you would make (extra credit for showing the number of spaces you moved)

Sample Input/Output:

```
X = 4
Y = 6 //(4 * 1.5)
Z = 3 // 6 / 2

0, 0, 0 //Start
2, 5, 2 // (+2, -2, +2)
1, 2, 2 // (+4, +4, +4)
3, 4, 0 // (+2, +2, -2)
1, 6, 2 // (-2, +2, +2)
3, 3, 3 // (-3, -3, -3)
1, 5, 1 // (-2, +2, -2)
0, 6, 2 // (-1, +1, -1)
7 Moves.
```

Comment: So the "winner" is shortest source, regardless of how optimal the steps are?

Comment: Correct.  As long as the answer is correct, the number of moves don't matter.  I just want to know how many it took because I'm that kind of guy...

Comment: This seems bizarre and pointless. Any back-story to the question, anything to draw our interest?

Comment: I think you've asked something thats just too difficult. I doubt anybody is going to answer

Comment: Some of your example movement vectors seem to violate the "move positively in at least two dimensions" rule

Comment: What does `x` equal in the matrix? Does it mean the ending `x` component is always 0? You _seriously_ need to clarify what everything is. What is the input, how do you get the max values, how do you get the end point?

Comment: It is only a real challenge if there is a goal to find the shortest path, for else just plugging in `rand()` somewhere will always find *some* solution, with no clever tricks needed to backtrace the best path etc.

Answer (score 2):

### Lua, 68 Characters

The long version below always solves the problem with one move by searching for the first all positive move that will solve problem.

```
x=...
y,z=x*3/2,x*3/4
a,b,c=0,y,math.ceil(z/2)
x,y,z=x+1,y+1,z+1
for i=1,math.huge do
  if (x*i)%y==b and (x*i)%z==c then x=x*i break end
end
print("0,0,0\n0,"..b..","..c.."//+"..x..",+"..x..",+"..x.."\n1 move.")
```

Output for x = 12:

```
0,0,0
0,18,5//+455,+455,+455
1 move.
```

Output for x = 1000:

```
0,0,0
0,1500,375//+557424868,+557424868,+557424868
1 move.
```

Seems like the search could be replaced with some simple algebraic equation. But why stop there? Rules are easier to bend in golfing then doing the actual work.

So, assuming that there is always a single 1 move answer, and that I do not have to disclose the "number of spaces you moved", here is the 68 character golfed answer:

```
x=...print("0,0,0\n0,"..(x*3/2)..","..math.ceil(x*3/8).."\n1 move.")
```

Comment: Interesting ... you proved the problem is worthless :)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica - Not Golfed

### Just to see if we can get the ball rolling

... and trying to understand the problem ....

```
f[x_] := (
   (* Init code *)
   xmax = x;
   ymax = 3 Round[xmax]/2;
   zmax = Round[ymax]/2;
   xobj = 0;
   yobj = ymax;
   zobj = Ceiling[zmax/2];
   p = Join[Permutations[{1, 1, -1}], {{1, 1, 1}}];
   Print["X = ", xmax, "\nY = ", ymax, "\nZ = ", zmax];

   (* Loop *)
   i = 0; 
   pos = {0, 0, 0}; 
   k = "Start";
   While[
    (npos= {Mod[pos[[1]], xmax+1], Mod[pos[[2]], ymax+1], Mod[pos[[3]], zmax+1]}) 
             != {xobj, yobj, zobj}, 
      i++;
      Print[npos, " // ", k];
      pos= npos+ (k= RandomInteger[{1,xmax}] p[[RandomInteger[{1, Length[p]}]]]);
   ];
   Print[npos, " // ", k];
   Print[i, " Moves"];
   );
```

Invoke with

```
 f[4]
```

Sample Output

```
X = 4
Y = 6
Z = 3
{0,0,0} // Start
{3,4,3} // {3,-3,3}
{0,0,2} // {-3,3,3}
{2,3,1} // {-3,3,3}
{0,6,2} // {3,3,-3}
4 Moves
```

[image]

Not sure if I'm following the rules ...

Comment: I'm not sure anyone knows the rules, not even OP